# What does ignore: [], mean in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery validation script that I borrowed and modified to fit my needs, and just above the rules section it has the following:

```
ignore: [],
```

What does this entry mean?

Thanks.

Full code:

```
$().ready(function () {

    // validate forgot password form on keyup and submit
    $("#forgotPasswordForm").validate({
        ignore: [],
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                remote: "remote/forgot.password.check.email.php"
            },
            "g-recaptcha-response": {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "Enter a valid email address",
                remote: "We could not locate that email<br />address in our system. Check<br />your entry and try again."
            },
            "g-recaptcha-response": {
                required: "Check the 'I'm not a robot' box"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks like it lets you ignore certain elements... https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore

Comment: It's just an empty array, it's not special to jQuery. If you didn't know this before hand I would suggest NOT grabbing random code and editing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value of the ignore is `[":hidden"]`.

So if you want to validate hidden fields, you have to override this by setting `ignore` to `[]`. Otherwise the validate would ignore all of the hidden fields.

Comment: Thanks. That would explain why a hidden field was not being validated. Learning every day.

Answer (score 2):

`ignore: []`

ignore is a parameter, that expects an array.

`[]` is an empty array, so there is nothing to ignore.

Take a look at the [JavaScript Array Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Edit: Take a look at the answer from twain, seems like the statement overwrites default behavior.

Comment: In addition: The default value of the ignore is `[":hidden"]`. So if you want to validate hidden fields, you have to override this by setting `ignore` to `[]`.

Comment: @twain your aside comment appears to be the crux of the question.  This answer implies that having/not having `ignore: []` are the same, while your comment implies they are different.  I suggest you add your comment as an answer.

Comment: @freedomn-m i added my comment as an answer. :)

Comment: I've added a reference to your answer to mine.

Answer (score 0):

https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

> ignore (default: ":hidden")
>   Type: Selector
>   Elements to ignore when validating, simply filtering them out. jQuery's not-method is used, therefore everything that is accepted by not() can be passed as this option. > Inputs of type submit and reset are always ignored, so are disabled elements.

the function ignore comes with a default value ( hidde all  element with a hidden attribute ). If you pass en empty array [] it will hide no elements.

ps: you should look documentation before posting questions.